# Pagination ignored on Spring Data REST search

Tags: pagination, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I am testing out Spring Boot with Spring Data REST and am having a problem with the pagination feature.  Here's the code:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(path="logEntry", exported=true)
public interface LogEntryRepository extends MongoRepository<LogEntry, String>{

    @RestResource(path="/username", rel="/username")
    Page<LogEntry> findByUsername(@Param("username") String username, Pageable pageable);

    @RestResource(path="/sessionId", rel="/sessionId")
    Page<LogEntry> findBySessionId(@Param("sessionId") String sessionId, Pageable pageable);

    @RestResource(path="/source", rel="/source")
    Page<LogEntry> findBySource(@Param("source") String source, Pageable pageable);

}
```

When I run the endpoint provided by the MongoRepository (`/logEntry?size=100`), pagination works fine.  If I try to hit any of my search endpoints and try to invoke pagination (for example: `/logEntry/search/source?source=1&size=100`), it ignores the pagination and always gives me 20 back.

Can anyone tell me how to either

1. increase the default page size or
2. make pagination work for the endpoints above?  (or both :))

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running into a variant of [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-384). It already has been resolved in the master and bugfix branch and is scheduled for the upcoming releases. Wouldn't mind if you give the snapshots (2.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) a try. If you see this working, perfect. If not, feel free to raise an issue containing a tiny sample (a test case preferably) that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the default page size you can specify `spring.data.rest.default-page-size` property from `application.properties`, e.g:

```
spring.data.rest.default-page-size=100
```